# Asterisk in regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the parts of the text line that are after colon. For example from this text

```
previous usc contact name:*assistant director of field education*

agency name:*development corporation
```

I want to get the following:

```
assistant director of field education

1010 development corporation
```

I tried the following regex

```
.*:\*?(.*)\**$
```

It did not work. What is working right now is this:

```
.*:\*?(.*)\*
```

I do not understand why it is working on the second line where it does not have asterisk, and regex requires asterisk. And I do not understand why the first regex does not work properly.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  What language are you using?  When I try your first regex in Python, it works - the only issue is that `.*` is also matching the asterisk.  You could fix this by changing it to `[^*]*`

Comment: When I test the first line it doesn't work because you have a trailing space character after the "$" - but if I take that out it works. Do you have a space at the end of your working code? Or just in this page?

Comment: 1. `$` by default means end of string. You might need `MULTILINE` flag if you want it to match end of *line* 2. Make sure the regex engine sees the escapes. Try to double them inside string literals in your source code: `'\\'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell:

The second regex `.*:\*?(.*)\*` works, because:

`.*` is matching:

- `previous usc contact name` and
- `agency name`

followed by `:\*` (escaped `*` means: match `*`).

`(.*)\*` is finally matching EVERYHTING until the LAST `*`.

(Assuming you missed the star in the last line, this matches:)

- `assistant director of field education` and
- `development corporation`

---

Why the first regex fails is hard to tell from the example given. `.*:\*?(.*)\**$` means, that the END OF THE LINE needs to be zero or multiple `*` (`\**`)

Assuming, your line breaks are as provided, it will only match `development corporation`, because the anchor `$` (line end) normaly bahaves in single-line mode, means "end of String". Therefore the regex is only able to match ONCE. If you change the modifier to be multiline-mode (meaning, `$` matches every `\r\n` rather than just the END OF STRING) will give you the required result.

---

SingleLine-Mode, matching:

- `development corporation`

  `.*:\*?(.*)\**$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tMQ8TzNdVe3jzS5y)

---

Multiline-Mode matching:

- `assistant director of field education` and
- `development corporation`

  `.*:\*?(.*)\**$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NYks3sdS-0Wsg84O)

---

The beavhiour of `^` and `$` depends on the modifier:

given the String

```
Hello
World
```

and using `^(.*)$` in single-line mode will match `Hello World`. Using the same pattern in multiline mode will match `Hello` and `World` in two different Matchgroups.

In SingleLine, the String will be handled by the regex engine like

```
^Hello
World$
```

In MultiLine Mode, the Engine threads it like

```
^Hello$
^World$
```